# Using fr default language when using the internationalization

Tags: ios, ipad

> Hello, I try create a multi language  app and i want  using  french as
>   default language. i create the en.lproj and fr.lproj. now haw
>   can i configure the app that when it will be opned the first time will
>   be in frensh lang.
>
> Thx

Answer (score 0):

This only depends of your setting you have defined on your mobile device/simulator:

Check `Settings -> General -> International` and change Region Format to `France`

Have a look to the [official doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html) if u haven't already.

Comment: i want for example when someone install the app it will be open in default with frensh language.

Comment: because when we install any app and this app not support some language  the default language used is english and i want use frensh

Answer (score 0):

Look at CFBundleDevelopmentRegion property in Info.plist. The documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html).

> CFBundleDevelopmentRegion (String - iOS, OS X) specifies the native
>   region for the bundle. This key contains a string value that usually
>   corresponds to the native language of the person who wrote the bundle.
>   The language specified by this value is used as the default language
>   if a resource cannot be located for the user’s preferred region or
>   language.

Comment: i have chaged the value en by fr but when i test by the simulator the language is english :/